# Firebase/Firestore Security rule not working for me

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I am working on a small PWA app/game written in Ionic/Angular with Firestore backend.  I am not using Google auth-- the user creates their own user name & password.  I have a 'users' collection in Firestore with 3 fields:  **username**, **password**, **deployment** and one collection **progress**.  I want to have a security rule where the user can only read/write his own progress.  I've tried the following rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{document=**} {
      // allow read, write;
      // allow read: request.data.username == rick';
      // allow read: if resource.data.username == 'rick';
      // allow read: if resource.data.username == request.resource.data.username;
         allow read: if request.resource.data.username == resource.data.username;
    }
  }
}
```

The last one on that list is what I **think** the rule should be from reading the doc, but I've tried it many different ways with no success.  I even tried hard-coding a user name as in the first two examples.  The error I get with that last rule in place is

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: 
Property resource is undefined on object. for 'list' @ L19
FirebaseError: 
Property resource is undefined on object. for 'list' @ L19
```

My code is as follows:

```
await this.db.collection<FirestoreUserInfo>('users',
        ref => ref.where('username', '==', username).where('deployment', '==', 'Alkmaar')).get()
```

I've worked on this directly in the Cloud instance, and with the local emulators.  The error is the same.

(I tried to include a screenshot of the emulator, with error, but I can't figure out how.)

Answer (score 0):

To get who is accessing you have to use `request.auth.token`. Not `request.resource.data`.

```
allow read: if request.auth.token.username == resource.data.username;
```

You can check [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth) to see what values does `request.auth.token` have.
`username` field is not defined in default. I'm assuming that you are using custom claims.

Comment: Thanks, N.F., for the reponse.  That did not solve it, either.  I used 'allow read: if request.auth.token.username == resource.data.username'  as you suggested.  The error is still: Property username is undefined on object. for 'list' @ L19.  I am not using any Google authentication, so I wouldn't expect there to be the username in the auth object.   When using the Emulator I can see the data objects, eg.  request.auth, request.method, request,path, etc.  There is an object resource with a data map that includes 'username: "rick"' which is the user name submitted by the app.

Comment: I am not using custom claims as I don't want to use Google auth.  I'm trying to use the "Data Validation' method of rules. as shown in this Google doc: (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions)

Comment: You got `Property username is undefined` because `request.auth.token` does not have `username` unless you use custom claims. You have either (1) use custom claims or (2) use the field that is available in default. Available fields in default are described in the document that I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: thanks, N.F., but I can't use custom claims or fields in the request.auth object because I'm not using Google Authentication.